# PHP File Upload (File Type) Filter

Tags: php

I am having a problem with some code:

This code works:

```
if (!($uploadFile_type == "image/gif")) {
    echo "Sorry, only GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Now, I want to do multiples so I'm trying this:

```
if (($uploadFile_type != "image/gif") || ($uploadFile_type != "image/jpg") || ($uploadfile_type != "image/png")) {  
    echo "Sorry, only GIF/JPG or PNG files are allowed.";
}
```

The problem is that whenever I upload .jpg files I get "Sorry, only GIF/JPG or PNG files are allowed."

Is there something wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your condition:

`if x or y` is evaluated as true if one of `x` or `y` is true. In your example jpg is for sure not equal to png, why it will always evaluate to true.

how it gets evaluated:

```
if(("image/jpeg" != "image/gif") || ("image/jpeg" != "image/jpeg") || ("image/jpeg" != "image/png"))
```

which gives:

```
if(true || false || true)
```

which is:

```
if(true)
```

instead change it to:

```
if (!($uploadFile_type == "image/gif" || $uploadFile_type == "image/jpeg" || $uploadfile_type == "image/png"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This..

```
$array = array('image/gif','image/jpg','image/png');
if(!in_array($uploadFile_type,$array)){
    echo "Sorry, only GIF/JPG or PNG files are allowed.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not make an array of valid values e.g,

```
$valid_image_types = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
```

and then check your file upload type in this array.

```
if (!in_array($uploadFile_type, $valid_image_types)) {  
     echo "Sorry, only GIF/JPG or PNG files are allowed.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $value = explode(".", $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(array_pop($value));
    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");   
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)== false)
    {
       $errors="Extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
       $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }    
    if(empty($errors)==true)
    {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/".$file_name);
       echo "Success";
    }else
    {
       print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only allow file type `image/png, image/jpg and image/png`

```
$uploadFile_type = "image/png";

if ($uploadFile_type != "image/gif" and $uploadFile_type != "image/jpg" and $uploadFile_type != "image/png") {
 echo "Sorry, only GIF/JPG or PNG files are allowed.";
}
```

A typo also in your code : `$uploadfile_type != "image/png")`

Its actually:

```
$uploadFile_type != "image/png"
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7df19f280468ff890e9548971f179d384b71095d)

Answer (score -1):

i have same issues and i try with this code  and it will working now

```
 if ($uploadFile_type != "image/gif") {  
             if($uploadFile_type != "image/jpg") {
                if($uploadfile_type != "image/png"){

                  echo "Sorry, only GIF/JPG or PNG files are allowed.";
                }
             }
          }
```